# Fullcalendar meteor events not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, calendar, fullcalendar

I've been working on a project for some time now with meteor and fullcalendar. I've managed to display the events on the calendar, but they dont show as soon as I add them to my collection, not even after I refresh the page, they only show if I click to change the date from the calendar, this is the image show the calendar with no events, but in the console we can see the array of events [image: calendar]

and this is after I click the "next" button and "back" on the top left.

[image: calendar2]

Can anybody help me?? below is my code... thanks

```
Template.home.rendered = function(){

    calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){

        var events = [];

        calEvents = Times.find();
        calEvents.forEach(function(evt) {
          events.push({
            id: evt._id,
            title: evt.title,
            start: evt.start,
            end: evt.end
          });
        });
        callback(events);
    },

      editable:false,
      duration: '00:30',
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    }).data().fullCalendar;
    };
```

Comment: Can you please post the publication function also?

Comment: Where is your console.log command located? What does `Times.find()` do? Normally if you're going to use the "events" callback function as above, it's because you're fetching the event data asynchronously from the server via ajax. Does this "find()" method get the events from the server? If so, does it run synchronously? Because if not, it will not return until after your code to pass the events to fullCalendar has already executed, which is probably why it appears not to work the first time. What you're seeing is likely to be simply a delayed reaction from an async ajax call.

Comment: @ADyson the `Times.find()` is looking into my Times Collection, and yes, the function does get the data from the server, but im running the application in my machine, I'm not sure if it is asynchronously or not. How could I fix that?

Comment: if it makes an ajax call, then almost certainly it'll be an asynchronous call. I would guess that to get the result you need to maybe supply a callback. Does it implement the promise API, perhaps? What does that function actually look like? Can you show the code for it?

Comment: @ADyson thats the whole code...im not running any other function

Comment: How can that be? There must be some code for Times.find() somewhere? That would seem to be the place to look for your issue. You didn't even explain where the logging to the console occurs - it's not in the code above.

Comment: @ADyson im telling you...I can share the whole project with you if you want, but that is the only place that I use Times.find()

Comment: I didn't ask where else you _use_ that method, I asked where it's _defined_. I don't need the whole project, I need enough code to reproduce your issue. Right now I have no idea what `Times` is, or what its `find()` method does. I assume it generates your events, so it's important. Nor do I know what code is causing those logs in the console, even.

Comment: @ADyson I see, so, `Times` is my collection, as you can see here: 

`Times = new Mongo.Collection("times");`

the `find()` method is to get what is in my collection, wich is an array of events.

Comment: so presumably Mongo is from some library or other? It would be useful to know, then we can check the documentation and see what the method does.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, i am using meteor, so it uses mongodb, my collection is on a folder called lib on the root of the project folder.

Comment: https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find says "On the client, there will be a period of time between when the page loads and when the published data arrives from the server during which your client-side collections will be empty.". Unhelpfully, it doesn't tell you how you can wait for the data to arrive before using the collection

Comment: @ADyson I see, the funny thing is, I have another collection to store employee info, and when I submit the form with the info, it shows automatically in the page...I was thinking that the problem was in the fullcalendar component

Comment: Maybe your employee data was already cached in the client by the time you do that, it's hard to know. Probably your best thing is either to load the event data server-side and just render it as JSON into the page directly, or research how you can wait until a collection has been loaded client-side before trying to do anything with it